# how to set current month name(string) and year in a textview?

Tags: android, calendar, textview

I tried stackoverflow code:

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext);
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
String ma=month_date.format(cal.getTime());
t1.setText(ma);
```

Expected output is: OCTOBER 2017

But output display like:O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
String monthname=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM - yyyy", new Date());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
t1.setText(monthname );
```

**or this**

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext);
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd - MMMM - yyyy");
String ma=month_date.format(cal.getTime());
t1.setText(ma);
```

Comment: Then unselect answer.

Comment: than try this **`SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd - MMMM - yyyy");`**

Comment: @prithsh, why to create a new variable for year, why cant you mention it in date format?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This format my Friend**

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use MMMM in your code:

```
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext);
    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM - yyyy");
    String ma=month_date.format(cal.getTime());
    t1.setText(ma);
```

Comment: Dear user, don't click the down vote without trying, if you have enough confidence that the above post is wrong, check and try it once, then down vote, but don't behave like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SimpleDateFormat month_date= new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");**

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext);
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat month_date= new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
String ma=month_date.format(cal.getTime());
t1.setText(ma);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this first get the date object from the calender

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date =  calendar.getTime();
```

then after get the month and year

```
 String stringMonth = (String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", date); 

 String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", date);
```

Hope this helps.